# grep results in more lines that the original file has

Tags: amazon-ec2, grep, cloud

I am grepping a few extremely large csv files(around 24 million rows each) using two mutually exclusive regex's to filter rows. I cannot share the regex's or the files(not that you would ever want to download them).

The idea is that rows that match regex A get piped into file A. Rows that match regex B get piped into file B.

What I end up with is about 5 million extra rows in the target files after this process completes.

The regex's are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive, and the line counts are correct.

The task is running on an Amazon EC2 node. Has anyone ever seen this kind of issue when running grep in the cloud?

Comment: Show your grep statements...

Comment: OK... its something like :

grep "^x" someFile.csv >> FileA.csv
grep "^y" someFile.csv >> FileB.csv

Where all lines either start with x or y.

Comment: Are you saying that you get lines that don't match the regexps?

Comment: Nope, I wish it were that simple.

As per my example in response to Ahmed Masud, someFile.csv will have say... 100 million lines(in reality split across 4 files) and the sum of the number of lines in FileA and FileB ends up being 105 million lines.

Comment: awk would be better than grep for this, it can write to both files in one pass.

Comment: If you can't find any lines in the output files that don't belong, the  possibilities are that either line counting is broken, or your assumption of exclusivity is wrong.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with smaller sample files? If you can't provide details, it's hard for us to answer.

Comment: I think the issue might have something to do with the massive i/o load. My question is if anyone else has seen this type of issue before on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: I doubt running on ec2 has anything to do with this issue. How are you going about counting the lines?

Comment: using grep -c to count the lines

Comment: Very important that you actually post the REAL regex for us to help you otherwise we're just taking uneducated guesses in the dark

Comment: Ahmed, all due respect and thank you for your responses, but I am not asking for help with a regex. No regex could be made that would result in grep outputting more lines than are in the source file. If you know of one, please post it, as I am sure people would want to know if this behavior is possible.
 
I have tested the regex on a smaller subset of the data and it does not produce extra lines and performs the intended result flawlessly. When it is run on the complete file it takes about an hour in total. This is the only time it produces extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk instead seems to fix the problem.

Thanks Barmar!